# Can SBT use the java 11 module path for project depencencies?

Tags: java, sbt, java-platform-module-system

I have used **SBT** to build a pure-java project. This project consists of multiple modules, and *projectB* depends on *projectA*.
Now after switching to *JDK 11*, this dependency should be modeled not via *classpath* but via *module path*.
Is it possible to tell **SBT** that module depencencies must be resolved via *module path* instead of the *classpat*h?
Basically I have set up a *inter-(sbt-)module* depencencs that says `projB.dependsOn(projA)` - so can I tell **SBT** somehow to put this depencency on the javac *module-path* instead of using the *classpath*? I see currently no way of doing that.

EDIT: Further analysis showed that I needed also to use normal library depencencies (from libraries on a nexus repository) as module depencencies. So the next question would be - how can I treat these library depencencies as module depencencies in **SBT**?

I do know that **SBT** is a *scala* build tool, and that it is something of a stretch to use it for a java-only project, but I use **SBT** for other (scala-)projects, and I do not want to introduce too many different build tools, until I really have to. So - is there a sbt-level solution for this?

EDIT: To clarify the issue - the project in question is a kind of open-source library which we modified. The SBT build file is from our organization, so I have to maintain it.
The project switched to using module-info classes, and it depends on other (binary-only) libraries via module path, if you include module-info.java in the compilation, that is.

So in our SBT build I have to use the module path for some of the external library depencencies.
Also the SBT-subprojects have dependencies on each other, i.e. we also have to use the module path for that.
Is there a way to tell SBT that:

- This library must be on the module path, and not on the classpath
- This project dependency must be on the module path, and not via classpath?

That is the core of the question. I may be able to write a plugin for the first problem (having not libraryDepencencies, but modularLibraryDepencencies for example) - but I do not yet know how I could handle the second part (tell a project that project depencencies must be on the module path and not on the class path).

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. If any part of your project is modular, the whole project is modular, with module-path for things that declare it (`module-info` class) and classpath (the "unnamed module") for everything else.  So as long as your projectB and projectA have `module-info` classes, that's where they'll go. Along with any external dependencies with `module-info`.   Other external dependencies will go into the unnamed module (class path). Is your question more detailed than this? If so I'm missing it.

Comment: My main problem is that there seems to be no (direct?) support in JPMS to using the JPMS - i.e. set the modulePath instead of the classPath, put dependencies on the module path and put dependend modules on the module path instead of using the class path.